# How can I use a MAX(ABS(decimal)) in a PIVOT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following PIVOT currently:

```
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR [Month] IN
    ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
)
```

I want to modify the MAX(Value) to MAX(ABS(Value)), but it gives me an error saying `Incorrect syntax near 'Value'. Expected '(' OR SELECT)`.  I tried doing a `SELECT MAX(ABS(-5.0001))` by itself and it works, so why doesn't it work when I use it within the pivot?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to do the absolute conversion`(abs)` in pivot source query

```
select * from 
(
select abs(value) value,... from yourtable
) a
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR [Month] IN
    ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
)
```

Comment: I'm going to go with this, but is there some reason why my query is considered incorrect?  As far as I know, a MAX(Value) will output the same type of data as a MAX(ABS(Value)).

Comment: @Lunyx - AFAIK you can use only aggregate inside pivot operator.